# how to refelct the variable used in making an instance from an object in its name?

Tags: django, python-3.x, reflection, introspection

I have this model in django:

```
class Level(Model):
    level = CharField(...)
```

I build some instances from this model:

```
[Level.objects.create(level='Grade {}'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 13)]
```

as a result, I have 12 instances. For example:

```
grade_11 = Level.objects.get(level='Grade 11')
```

What I want to do is that I build all grade_1 to grade_12 in one line. I know it is called introspection or reflection in python but I do not know how to it. I tried this but it was not successful:

```
['grade_{}'.format(i) = ProgramLevel.objects.get(program_level='Grade {}'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 13)]
```

Comment: Please don't do that, that is bad design... Use a dictionary or a list to collect the values.

Comment: I just want to avoid naming each instance manually and making it DRY. Can you please let me know what do you mean by an alternative to the code? And what and why it is a bad design?

Comment: It's bad design because you're throwing whatever happens to be in the `Level` model into your namespace in a pretty opaque way. A better way to do this would be to actually define a numeric field on `Level`, probably `SmallIntegerField`, and using that when you're creating objects or querying the ORM (or just use a `level` field with the `choices` attr rather than having a model for it). If you want to find a better approach to this, you might want to start a separate question (possibly on a different StackExchange site) to get feedback on what problem you're actually attempting to solve here.

Comment: What I am actually doing is that I am in the phase of development. Each time I drop the database I have to fill up the database again so that I can test and see what happens. What I wrote above is just a script I have written that I execute in the shell using ```exec(open('populate_database.py').read())``` . It is not a part of  a model or view. I just need each program level as an object to use in populating the Program model not mentioned in here

Comment: Any answer to the original question?